# My friend used to

Tags: grammar, modal-verbs, grammaticality-in-context

1. My friend used to visit me every Saturday when I was ill
2. John is used to getting up early in the morning

In first sentence "used to" is used.
In second sentence "is used to" is used how could anybody explain it clearly please?

Comment: What research on this topic have you done?

Comment: Venkatesh - What @Bill is asking is, “What have you done to try to answer this question yourself?” For example, have you looked up “used to” in a dictionary? Or Googled `How to use “used to” correctly` to find a website like [this one](http://www.5minuteenglish.com/mar20.htm)? You probably won’t get many upvotes if you just come here and keep asking, “Can anyone explain this please?” We like questions that delve into more detail about what you have figured out, and why you still need more help. See our [Details, Please meta post](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/439) for more tips.

Answer (score 1):

"***Used to***" is a **phrasal modal verb**. That is to say, it is a set phrase that acts as a verb (hence *phrasal*) and that verb is used to alter another verb in certain ways (depending on what sort of modification it causes, such a verb might be *modal* or just *auxiliary*). It expresses that something was done in the past, and is not done any longer. It would usually be something that was done continuously ("*I used to like him*") or habitually ("*I used to go to the gym*").

"***Used to***" is also an **adjective that takes a noun phrase**, indicating that the person (or other entity) it is applied to is accustomed to whatever that noun phrase indicates. For example, it could indicate an environmental condition ("*Bob is used to hot weather*") or an activity, using a gerund phrase ("*Bob is used to hiking long distances*")

Your first sentence is in the **modal verb** sense; your second is in the **adjective** sense.

In the modal verb sense, it might occur with an **implicit** main verb, either taken from a question:

> "Do you like seafood?"
>
> "I used to."

Or from earlier in the sentence:

> "I don't read as much as I used to."

Answer (score 0):

In the first sentence, it's a modal verb roughly equal to *had a habit of.*

In the second sentence, it's an adjective meaning *accostumed (to.)*